# Fetch all events from EventStore EventKit iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, sdk, fetch, eventkit

i would like to know how to fetch all events from an EventStore using EventKit in iOS.

This way i can specify all events for today:

```
- (NSArray *)fetchEventsForToday {

    NSDate *startDate = [NSDate date];

    // endDate is 1 day = 60*60*24 seconds = 86400 seconds from startDate
    NSDate *endDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:86400];

    // Create the predicate. Pass it the default calendar.
    NSArray *calendarArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject:defaultCalendar];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [self.eventStore predicateForEventsWithStartDate:startDate endDate:endDate calendars:calendarArray]; 

    // Fetch all events that match the predicate.
    NSArray *events = [self.eventStore eventsMatchingPredicate:predicate];

    return events;
}
```

The correct should use a NSPredicate, which is created with:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [self.eventStore predicateForEventsWithStartDate:startDate endDate:endDate calendars:calendarArray];
```

I have tried using

```
distantPast
distantFuture
```

as startDate and endDate, no good.
So other A's from other Q's are not exaclty wha im looking for.

Thank you!

---

**EDIT**

I have tested and got to the conclusion that i can only fetch events in a period of 4 years maximum. Any way of getting past this? Without using multiple fetches..

Comment: Do you need the list of expired event?

Comment: Exactly, every event on the calendar. past and future.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Code for fetch all events into array :

```
NSDate *start = ...
NSDate *finish = ...

// use Dictionary for remove duplicates produced by events covered more one year segment
NSMutableDictionary *eventsDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:1024];

NSDate* currentStart = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:0 sinceDate:start];

int seconds_in_year = 60*60*24*365;

// enumerate events by one year segment because iOS do not support predicate longer than 4 year !
while ([currentStart compare:finish] == NSOrderedAscending) {

    NSDate* currentFinish = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:seconds_in_year sinceDate:currentStart];

    if ([currentFinish compare:finish] == NSOrderedDescending) {
        currentFinish = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:0 sinceDate:finish];
    }
    NSPredicate *predicate = [eventStore predicateForEventsWithStartDate:currentStart endDate:currentFinish calendars:nil];
    [eventStore enumerateEventsMatchingPredicate:predicate
                                      usingBlock:^(EKEvent *event, BOOL *stop) {

                                          if (event) {
                                              [eventsDict setObject:event forKey:event.eventIdentifier];
                                          }

                                      }];       
    currentStart = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:(seconds_in_year + 1) sinceDate:currentStart];

}

NSArray *events = [eventsDict allValues];
```

Comment: Thank you Dmitry! i will try it and come back! No one could answer this simple question, lets hope you did!

Comment: This code will work, except that it consolidates all recurring events by only showing the final event returned, since it uses eventIdentifier as the hash key, and all recurring events have the same hash key.                                 if (event) {
                                             [eventsDict setObject:event forKey:[event.eventIdentifier stringByAppendingString:[event.startDate description]]];
                                         }

Comment: Watch out: not each year has 365 days.. So hardcoding that is not the best solution.

Comment: You may want to call predicateForEventsWithStartDate in a different thread.

Answer (score 0):

This is the method I am using in my app to fetch them.

```
    NSDate *startDate = [NSDate distantPast];       
    NSDate *endDate = [NSDate distantFuture];
```

Comment: does this return all the past "done" events? Does this return all the events if i have events starting 2002?

Comment: It should I have only used it for all the future

Comment: this wont wont work further than 4 years, a 4-year period maximum  (future or past), any ideas? or have this worked for you this way?

Comment: I have never went past 2 years sorry.

Comment: This may have worked at one time but in iOS 9 it is not working. Apple now seems to limit the span between `startDate` and `endDate` to 4 years.

Answer (score -1):

This is code **in production**

```
const double secondsInAYear = (60.0*60.0*24.0)*365.0;
NSPredicate* predicate = [eventStore predicateForEventsWithStartDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:-secondsInAYear] endDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:secondsInAYear] calendars:nil];
```

For you, I would recommend looking back and forward ten years.

Comment: the problem is, when i try to go further than one year the predicate returns 0 objects from the store.

Comment: No, I have not tried going further--I guess the magic is one year.

Comment: So you suggest doing multiple fetches? I need every event, past and future. recurring or not recurring, etc.

Comment: Watch out: not each year has 365 days.. So hardcoding that is not the best solution.