# Predicate for EKEvents failed to init my end date

Tags: ios, ekevent

I'm stuck with a fetching request on EKEvents.

Following Apple samples, I created two dates 20 yrs before now, and 20 yrs in the future.

```
NSDateComponents *twentyYearsAgoComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
twentyYearsAgoComponents.year = -20;
NSDate *twentyYearsAgo = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateByAddingComponents:twentyYearsAgoComponents
                                                                       toDate:[NSDate date]
                                                                      options:0];

// Create the end date components

NSDateComponents *twentyYearsFromNowComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
twentyYearsFromNowComponents.year = 20;
NSDate *twentyYearsFromNow = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateByAddingComponents:twentyYearsFromNowComponents
                                                                           toDate:[NSDate date]
                                                                          options:0];



NSPredicate *predicate = [self.eventStoreGD predicateForEventsWithStartDate:twentyYearsAgo endDate:twentyYearsFromNow calendars:@[self.calendarForEventGD]]; // nil = all calendars

NSLog(@"predicate : %@",predicate);
```

In the console, I printed this :

```
2015-04-10 14:52:52.825 ohmygoods[1658:270016] [dateFormatter stringFromDate:twentyYearsFromNow] : 2035-04-10
2015-04-10 14:53:06.120 ohmygoods[1658:270016] predicate : EKEventPredicate start:10/04/1995 14:51; end:10/04/1999 14:51; cals:(
"x-apple-eventkit:///Calendar/p11"
```

)

You see

```
end:10/04/1999 14:51
```

Instead of 10/04/2035 ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19823486/why-eventsmatchingpredicate-returns-nil)!

You can't fetch more than 4 years from the start date.
Don't ask why...