# iOS - Fetch Events from Custom Calendar

Tags: ios, objective-c, calendar, ekeventstore, ekcalendar

Following is the code I'm using to fetch the events from Calendar, but I always get the array `nil`.

```
EKEventStore *eventStore = AppContext.HSCalendar.eventStore;
NSPredicate *predicate = [eventStore predicateForEventsWithStartDate:[NSDate distantPast] endDate:[NSDate distantFuture] calendars:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[eventStore calendarWithIdentifier:AppContext.HSCalendar.selectedCalendarID]]];
NSArray *arrEvent = [eventStore eventsMatchingPredicate:predicate];
```

How can I get all the events from the custom calendar?

Comment: check StartDate&endDate Format is same as in the Array on which you are using Predicate

Comment: I'm fetching it from the EventStore

Comment: You can get help from this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6077613/fetch-all-events-from-eventstore-eventkit-ios