# Swift - retrieving all events from calendar and get event's participates

Tags: ios, swift, calendar, swift3, eventkit

In my app I am trying to get all the events that happened during a specific time. This is the code I have:

```
    let store = EKEventStore()
    store.requestAccess(to: EKEntityType.event) { (granted, error) in
   if(granted){
      let calendars = store.calendars(for: EKEntityType.event)
      for calendar in calendars {
      let predicate = store.predicateForEvents(withStart: (dates.first?.dateObject)!, end: (dates.last?.dateObject)!, calendars: [calendar])

                store.enumerateEvents(matching: predicate){ (event, stop) in
                    print(event.title)

                }

            }

        }else{
        print(error)
        }
```

The problem with this is that it retrieve only birthdays, and dons't retrieve events created by the user or holidays in that day. 
Here is the output I get:
Kate Bell’s Birthday
Kate Bell’s Birthday
Kate Bell’s Birthday
Kate Bell’s Birthday
John Appleseed’s Birthday
John Appleseed’s Birthday
John Appleseed’s Birthday
John Appleseed’s Birthday
Anna Haro’s Birthday
Anna Haro’s Birthday
Anna Haro’s Birthday
Anna Haro’s Birthday
David Taylor’s Birthday
David Taylor’s Birthday
David Taylor’s Birthday
David Taylor’s Birthday

- So how could I make it work so I could get all events including the one made by the user on its calendar.
- And How could I retrieve the participants of each event?

Comment: This may help http://stackoverflow.com/a/8888550/6724849

Comment: How will i get the participants of each event ?

Answer (score 0):

To fetch events from all calendars assign nil to calendars parameter of instance method predicateForEvents(withStart:end:calendars:).

```
let predicate = store.predicateForEvents(withStart: (dates.first?.dateObject)!, end: (dates.last?.dateObject)!, calendars: nil)
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/eventkit/ekeventstore/1507479-predicateforevents

Comment: till iOS 11 this methods returning all types of events but in iOS 12, it does not returning Exchange Events such as outlook calendar events.

Comment: @GvSharma ...hey means if i am sending nil in IOS 12 then can't get any event from all calendar?...can you give brief that details or reference link?