# How can I retrieve calendar event of only the current day?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, eventkit

I want to retrieve the data/events of the present date in my `tableView`, I think I need to use `EventKit` for that but not sure how to.

This is what I tried, but doesnt seem to work: It shows only the sections but not the label for Events

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate{

@IBOutlet weak var taskShow: UITableView!
var titles : [String] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let eventStore = EKEventStore()

    switch EKEventStore.authorizationStatus(for: .event) {
    case .authorized:
        readEvents()
    case .denied:
        print("Access denied")
    case .notDetermined:

        eventStore.requestAccess(to: .event, completion: { (granted: Bool, NSError) -> Void in
            if granted {
                self.readEvents()

            }else{
                print("Access denied")
            }



        })
    default:
        print("Case Default")
    }
    self.taskShow.reloadData()
}

func readEvents() {


    let eventStore = EKEventStore()
    let calendars = eventStore.calendars(for: .event)

    for calendar in calendars {
        if calendar.source.title == "Work" {
            let oneMonthAgo = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: -30*24*3600)
            let oneMonthAfter = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: +30*24*3600)


            let predicate = eventStore.predicateForEvents(withStart: oneMonthAgo as Date, end: oneMonthAfter as Date, calendars: [calendar])

            var events = eventStore.events(matching: predicate)

            for event in events {

                titles.append(event.title)
  }}}}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return titles.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath as IndexPath)


    cell.textLabel!.text = titles[indexPath.row]
    // Configure the cell...

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6077613/fetch-all-events-from-eventstore-eventkit-ios it will help you

Comment: I think you are getting events but u have to reload table in readEvents()....may be it'll work.

Comment: @PradeepKashyap no its not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can use EventKit for reading calendar event.Apple has documented the use of EventKit.please refer below Apple link for detail.
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/EventKitProgGuide/ReadingAndWritingEvents.html

Comment: I need to use Swift 3

Comment: for swift please refer this tutorial link https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2016/04/28/listing-calendar-events-with-event-kit-and-swift/